# How will my form 1 know that the checkbox is enabled from form 2?

Tags: c#, checkbox

This is my form 2, this is where the checkboxes are.

[image]

My operator in here which is on the middle, has a random character generator, which my code is this :

```
        char[] select = new char[] { '+', '-', '/', '%', '*' };
        var rand = new Random();
        char num = select[rand.Next(5)];
        lbloperator.Text = Convert.ToString(num);
```

If the only check is addition, my form 1 will only perform addition, or if add,subtract, my form 1 will only perform add and subtract. Please help me with this! :(

FORM1

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is tow ways to do that:

1- first way is define public property in form2 that can tell form1 the status of checkBox1:

Form2:

```
public bool MyCheckBoxStatus
{
    get {return checkBox1.Checked;}
}
```

Form 1 (For Example):

```
Form2 frm = new Form2;
frm.ShowDialog();

if (frm.MyCheckBoxStatus)
{
    //Do something...
}
```

2- The other way: if you are using Windows Forms Application then all your controls have a property named Modifiers change its value to public and write this code in Form1:

```
Form2 frm = new Form2;
frm.ShowDialog();

if (frm.checkBox1.Checked)
{
    //Do something...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, glad it worked! but there's a problem, it is showDialog, so every time i press the button, it keeps on opening. -.-  Anyway, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: You can use Show() method if you want, but be worry the the Show() method causes: 1- the Form1 will not wait to user response. 2- User can return to Form1 without close Form2.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure exactly what you are asking, but it sounds like you are trying to pass some data between forms.

In Form2, you can add a public property that reads your label

```
public string TheOperator {
    get { return lblOperator.Text; }
}
```

Then from Form1, you can create a new instance of form2 and then reference the Property when needed.

```
Form2 fm = new Form2();
fm.Show();
string theOp = fm.TheOperator;
```

//////////

In response to your edit:
You can add this to Form1, exposing the operator variable there:

```
public string MyOperator {
    get { return lblOperator.Text; }
    set {
                lblOperator.text = value;
                //You can perform any updates to 
                //your calculations here, or call 
                //another method to do so
        }
}

private void OpenForm2()
{
    Form2 frm2 = new Form2(this);
    frm2.Show();
}
```

Then inside of Form2, you pass a reference to Form1 so that you can access the public property:

```
private Form1 frm;
public New(Form1 _frm)
{
    frm = _frm;
}

private void UpdateOperator()
{
    //call this method, calculating your operator and then
        //set the operator on the first form (variable frm) to
        //What you need it to do
    frm.MyOperator = lblOperator.Text;
}
```

Comment: sorry for my bad english though, i just want to pass the data from my form2 to form1, if the chkbxAdd was checked, then on my form1, the lbloperator will only display "+", now if on form 2, it is all enabled, my form1 will display the selected operators. For example, i enabled them all, then the possible output would be, 1+1,1-1,1*1,1/1,1%1 , something like that.

Comment: It says here that method must have a return type.
public New(Form1_frm)

it highligted the 'New'

Comment: I'm sorry sir but i am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public partial class Form2: Form
{
public string checkBoxSelected = "";
}


public partial class Form1 : Form
{
private void MakeResult()
{
Form2 result = new Form2();
result.checkBoxSelected = "+";
result.Show();
}
}
```